# Continue execution after StackOverflowException thrown

Tags: vb.net, exception, automation

I am currently involved in a software testing project and is testing a closed libarary in VB.NET that have a small probability of crashing due to StackOverflowExceptions.
The reason this exception will be thrown is out of my control. From my understanding I will not be able to handle this type of error without fixing the code that causes it, which I am unable to do.

Is there any way of limiting what part of the application a StackOverflowException damages or am I required to create a whole new process for each of the tests to avoid crashing the application?

```
Sub runTests() as boolean     
  'testObject1 will throw StackOverflowException
  testObject1.runTest()
  testObject2.runTest()
  testObject3.runTest()      
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "limiting what part of the application a StackOverflowException damages"?

Comment: I might have been somewhat unclear, I meant if there is a way to limit the stack a part of the application can use. Think this is more related to how threads handle their stack. If a threads use a local stack, by using multiple threads this might be able to prevent the the main thread state from exiting? Think I might need to study how VB handle their stack.

Comment: A stack overflow damages every single part of the stack, because without it you have no room for storing the stack pointer when calling a procedure, you can't pop values back off the stack reliably to return (because it may be an invalid location), you can't allocate local variables, etc. A stack overflow is fatal. The solution: contact the vendor of that library and tell them to fix the problem properly, or find a different library written by someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Much appreciated! Unfortunately this is not an acceptable solution, our applications purpose is to validate this library and find possible faults that may occur. When a fault is found, the series of test should continue. Maybe the only way to continue execution is to divide the different tests into standalone programs that an external test suite will be executing?

Comment: One solution is to run until the SO occurs (which tells you which particular test failed), and then disable that test (since you know it has failed) and restart testing. Another alternative would be to move the test that is causing the SO to the end of the tests, so that everything else has been run before the SO occurs. There is no way to continue the execution after the SO without restarting the application, though.